# Resolving Runtime error "91" after VBA Crash which worked find before the crash

Tags: excel, vba

I hope someone can help me.  Was almost done with everything and my excel crashed.  Before the crash everything worked fine. Now I get a Runtime error on this line "ActiveCell.Find(i).Select." --- Below is my procedure which searches a file for a particular value, finds it and then goes to the last row containing that value.

```
Sub FindValue_Raw()

Dim Value As Variant
Dim Sheetname As String
Dim lastCell As String
Dim x As Integer
Dim iVal As Integer
Dim i As Variant

Value = InputBox("Enter Value:", "Input")

Sheetname = "Sheet2"

Dim Cell As Variant

    'Search in Column A | MatchCase True = case sensitive of raw file
    Set Cell = Sheets(Sheetname).Columns("C:C").Find(What:=Value, After:=Sheets(Sheetname).Range("C1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not Cell Is Nothing Then
    'Find how many rows have this value
     iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C1:C480000"), Cell)
    'find the last line with this value
     Do While x < iVal
        'Set where the curse is after it finds value
         i = Cell
        **'Select first instance of that value -THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS
         **ActiveCell.Find(i).Select****
         'Finds the last Reference address
         lastCell = ActiveCell.Address(False, False)
         'Highlights cell
        ' ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
          x = x + 1
    Loop
    ' Next
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    'Value is found, Highlight Cell
    'Sheets(Sheetname).Range(Cell.Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
Else
    'Value Not found
    MsgBox "Not Found"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the `ActiveCell` the correct cell at run-time?

Comment: Also [this MS page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/object-variable-not-set-error-91) provides info on error 91 including causes.

Comment: Yes -  ActiveCell  is where it errors

Comment: What is the `ActiveCell` when the error occurs?

Comment: ActiveCell.Find(i).Select -   Cell   - is "1703"  which is what I put in the in the input box. That is fine .   i also passes the 1703.  Then it craps out.

Answer (score 1):

You're making a member call against the result of `Range.Find`. When `Range.Find` doesn't find what it's looking for, it returns `Nothing` - and you can't call `.Select` on `Nothing`.

That's exactly what you're guarding against here:

```
Set Cell = Sheets(Sheetname).Columns("C:C").Find(...)
If Not Cell Is Nothing Then
    '...
End If
```

You need to do the same thing here:

> ```
> ActiveCell.Find(i).Select
> ```

That is, declare a local variable *and validate that `Range.Find` succeeded*:

```
Dim somethingMeaningful As Range
Set somethingMeaningful = ActiveCell.Find(i) '<~ TODO recondiser whether ActiveCell is really needed
If Not somethingMeaningful Is Nothing Then
    somethingMeaningful.Select '<~ TODO reconsider whether this is really needed
End If
```

Side note, [Rubberduck](http://www.github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) (free, open-source VBE add-in project that I manage) can warn about such unguarded `Range.Find` calls (they have to be early-bound though), implicit `ActiveSheet` and `ActiveWorkbook` references, and other code issues.